# Winter Bash: Who's winning?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2014

So, not to make this a competition or anything... but who's winning?  Is there a leaderboard for who has the most hats?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure there is. HATZ *IS* THE GREATEST COMPETITION EVER!!! if you don't know (so you don't need to make it a competition again).

Just go to http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/leaderboard to look at the current winners.

Comment: I was first on SO until I woke up the next day :c

Comment: @Qix: sorry....

Comment: @nneonneo Yeah where the heck did you come from? The leaderboards were neck and neck and then all of a sudden you have a million hats. Lame... :|

Comment: @Qix: I don't have a million yet. Also I've been here for like forever, seriously. And I did not expect to get so many hats; I got a few hats by being *exceptionally* lucky.

Answer (score 15):

Everyone is winning!

While this event does tend to affect the overall inner workings by offering slightly weighted incentives which would otherwise be simply routine, it is still an awesome endeavor.

After all, it is the hat season, and all us cats are dressed up and ready to take the town :)

[image]

<sub>There is a leaderboard as noted by [@nicael](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245493/178816)</sub>

Comment: Nice pic :) Who is *she* looking at?

Comment: +1 for the majestic feline.

Comment: @nicael - Wasn't aware it was a female cat :P But that doesn't make it any less awesome :D I would assume she is looking to the future to find more hats!

Comment: Yes i also like it

Answer (score 15):

Just got this today from an asian restaurant (I kid you not). I appear to have the universe on my side.

> [image]

Comment: That is so perfect.  Wow.

Comment: I think the weird looks of the waitresses when I started laughing hysterically were worth it.

Comment: lol, they *knew* that... :D